# Get a reference to view controller on current stack

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

How do I create a pointer from witihin one controller to another controller that is already on the stack and created by a StoryBoard.

For example, I use the method `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to load a view controller onto the stack/screen.

I know there is another controller behind this, still loaded called InitialViewController (class). How do I get a reference/pointer to the controller that I know is there.

If I try and log out presentedViewController or presentingViewController from self/navigationController they return null.
NSLog(@"presented: %@",self.navigationController.presentedViewController);

EDIT - more information on view controllers in app

1. Initial View Controller loaded (sub class of [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController))
2. Depending if user logged in

   Welcome View Controller loaded (this is a navigation stack including Welcome/Login/Signup)
   Home View Controller loaded (navigation stack with home VC as the root)

Basically the initial view controller has a property of topViewController which is set to Home (nav stack) or Welcome (nav stack).

The initial view controller is always on the current display (just never seen).

How do I reference this, or create a pointer to it. For example, if I was within the imp file for the Login VC how do I control/link to the view on the initial view controller without recreating it with alloc/init?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using UITabBarController, you can get references to its child UIViewControllers via:

```
[myTabBarController objectAtIndex:index];
NSLog(@"Selected view controller class type: %@, selected index: %d", [myTabBarController selectedViewController], [myTabBarController selectedIndex]);
```

The zero-based indexing scheme follows the order of the tabs as you've set them up, whether programmatically or through IB (leftmost tab = index 0).

Because the  UIViewController reference you appear to be searching for seems to be the rootViewController (because of the way you named it; 'InitialViewController'), you can also try this in your appDelegate. This will take 5 seconds:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{

    NSLog(@"self.window.rootViewController = %@", NSStringFromClass([self.window.rootViewController class]));

    UIViewController *myRootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

}
```

Let me know if that does the trick :)

Whether you're using a UITabBarController or UINavigationController, I'm certain one of those is your rootViewController. Once you grab the reference to it, the rest is pretty easy:

```
InitialViewController* myInitialViewController;

for (UIViewController *vc in [myRootViewController childViewControllers]) {
    if([vc isKindOfClass:[InitialViewController class]]){
        //Store this reference in a local/global variable or a property, 
        //or simply perform some logic on the vc pointer if you don't need to store it.
        myInitialViewController = (InitialViewController *)vc; //Example & reminder to cast your reference
    }
}
```

EDIT BASED ON NEW DETAILS FOUND IN COMMENTS:

Ok, run this code in your topViewController's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear:

```
//You have to import this class in order to reference it
#import "MESHomeViewController.h"

//Global variable for storing the reference (you can make this a property if you'd like)
MESHomeViewController *myHomeVC;

int i = 0;
for (UIViewController *vc in [self.slidingViewController childViewControllers]) {
    NSLog(@"Current vc at index %d = %@", i, [vc class]);

    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[MESHomeViewController class]]) {

        NSLog(@"Found MESHomeViewController instance - [[self.slidingViewController childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:%d]", i);
        myHomeVC = vc;
        break;

    }
    i++;
}
```

See if the reference is available to you there. If it is, your console will print out the class name of your HomeViewController.

Comment: I have updated my question with an edit which provides more information on what I am trying to achieve. Please let me know.

Comment: OK, I cloned that repo and I have the example project loaded. If you look in the example project's storyboard, which ViewController are you in (metaphorically) and which are you trying to reference?

It would make it a lot easier to answer your question that way.

Comment: Thanks, its hard to explain. Lets say I have my Login VC on screen. This would mean in stack order it would be like this InitalViewController (bottom), the topViewController property of this would be the 'WelcomeVC' (which is a navigation controller), then the Login View Controller showing. How do I access the view property of the Initial View Controller that is loaded? (from within the imp file of the login view controller on screen)

Comment: Okay, correct this if I misunderstand anything:

Your InitialViewController is like the InitialSlidingViewController in the example project, just an instance of ECSlidingViewController.

Your InitialViewController's topViewController property is set to your WelcomeVC. This is the first view presented to the user on-screen.

From the WelcomeVC, the user navigates to the LoginViewController.

Are you trying to get the reference to the WelcomeVC or something else from the LoginViewController.m?

Comment: I am trying to get a reference to the HomeViewController.view from the LoginViewController. It is so I can pass a HUD onto the Home View Controller

Comment: That's the only gap I need you to fill for me. "The initial view controller...always on the current display (just never seen)" What is the name of that initial view controller? Is it the same as the InitialViewController that is an instance of the ECSlidingViewController? Is that what you're trying to reference? EDIT: Just read your last comment. I think I understand now, just give me a few minutes and I'll get back to you on it.

Comment: Read my latest edit and let me know if you see the HomeViewController class name printed to your console.

Comment: Thanks @BigDan - the class of my home view controller is already known it is called MESHomeViewController. I just need to know how to control/interact/create a pointer to that view controller already on the stack, created by the storyboard

Comment: You're welcome. If that code prints "MESHomeViewController" from your LoginViewController's viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear, then you can capture the reference.

I'm going to edit it again showing how to do that.

Comment: Hey @StuartM I'm just curious -- did it work out for ya? I believe that should be the ticket.

Comment: Not really :) I am struggling to understand this. I couldn't start a chat as you didnt hav enough reputation :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28401/discussion-between-stuartm-and-bigdan)